# remove id and index.php via htaccess in subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, redirect, friendly-url

current URL:

> ```
> domain/index.php?id=p123
> ```

I want:

1. add www
2. remove:index.php
3. remove 'id' form URL

I do it this way:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=302,L,NE]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

it works if domian is without sub directory.

how can I change this code to support sub directory too like this:

> ```
> domian/subdirectory/index.php?id=p123
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll go about it this way:

First, redirect non-www URLs to www ones:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s ^on(s)|
RewriteRule ^ http%1://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

Rewrite the friendly URLs to respective `index.php` files:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*/)?([^/]+)$ /$1index.php?id=$2 [L]
```

Next, handle the raw URIs with `index.php` in them:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ /(.*/)?(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=301,L]
```

The last rule will also take care of URLs like `domain.com/dir/?id=sth` and `domain.com/dir/index.php?id=sth`

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with the following changes:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /(.*/|)(?:index\.php)?\?id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1%2? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php
RewriteRule ^(.*/|)([^/]*)$ $1index.php?id=$2 [L]
```

We know that `%{THE_REQUEST}` has the format `GET /path/to/index.php?id=12312412 HTTP/1.1` or something along those lines. In the first rule we match `\`, which is a literal space, then the beginning slash that is always there. `(.*/|)` will match everything until index.php, or exactly nothing. The same trick we do in the second rule. I have added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php` to prevent an infinite loop when index.php does not exist for a particular directory.

Comment: heh, quite similar answer to mine ^_^. Though I beat you to it by a minute ;-)

Comment: @hjpotter92 But my answer contains two extra `|`'s and your answer does not. So: Hah, joke's on you, I won! ;-)